# Convert Task<String> to String in Windows 8 apps

Tags: c#, windows, string

I writing a Windows 8 app. I have a code :

```
public async Task<string> readweb()
    {
        var uri = new Uri(@"http://stackoverflow.com/");
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var data = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
        string text = data;
        return text;
    }
```

i want to get web-data by `string data = readweb();` but it error "cannot convert task to string". Help me! Thanks!

Comment: Well yes, you'll need to await it in the calling code... do you understand what a `Task<string>` represents?

Comment: can you tell me about it ? @JonSkeet thanks!

Comment: If you're new to async, you should really read a tutorial on it. It's not the sort of thing that is easily done in comments here...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Do like this,

```
public async Task<string> readweb()
    {
        var uri = new Uri(@"http://stackoverflow.com/");
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var data = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
        string text = data;
        return text;
    } 

private async void Something()
{
    var data = await readweb();
}
```